# Storing a probability distribution without saving single values

Tags: algorithm, math, memory, probability, distribution

I am calculating many (~ 100 million) floating point values during an operation. I do not want to store them all in the memory but I want to save a rough distribution of the collection.

My idea was to determine the exponents of all values and count them in a histogram. But this, of course, works only if the values have different exponents.

Has anybody an idea how I can do this without knowing how the distribution looks like?

Comment: It depends on how rough you're willing to be. Also, do you have any idea of the range of values? Are they all between, say, 0 and 1 million?

Comment: As explained in several answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35220, you can store an arbitrarily accurate and often incredibly compressed representation of any empirical distribution by approximating the graph of its distribution function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest randomly saving some, then making a histogram after the fact from that.  For example if you randomly save 0.1% of the numbers then you'd only need to save 100,000, from which you can calculate a highly accurate distribution.

You can reduce the number of calls to rand() by calling it every time you save a number to find a random number in the range `1..2000`, then wait that many numbers before saving the next.

Comment: If the input data are sufficiently random/evenly distributed, you could get away with just sampling every _n_th datum, as well, eliminating the need for a random number generator at all.

Comment: @Tomboyo I thought of that, but I've personally seen too many "synchronization artifacts" to want to do that.

Comment: I concur. I've often gotten skewed results with "Every nth" sampling.

Answer (score 1):

If you approximately know the min and max values, I'd think a binning strategy would be a good choice.  Here is an outline for what I mean:

Figure out how many bins you need
For all my numbers
    Find the bin that this number goes in 
    Increment that bin

Answer (score 0):

Another useful alternative would be to compute on-the-fly moments of the distribution, and then reconstruct PDF from moments

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)

https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/ELECTRONIC_PAPERS/JAOT07.CES.pdf